# How do I check if a mysql row result is empty?

Tags: c++, mysql

How do I check to see if the mysql row results are empty in c++?

The following code I have doesn't work properly.

I am wanting to check to see if a row with the license key, and an empty field called HWID, and if the license key code is there, and the hwid isn't there, I want to enter a hwid value into the hwid field. Basically I was wondering if my code for checking if the query results are valid or not.

```
if (hwid == row[i])
{
return true;
}
else if((row[i] == NULL) || row[i] == "")
{
int qstate2 = 0;
stringstream ss;
ss << "INSERT INTO eNVYCSGO (HWID) VALUES ('" + hwid + "') WHERE licenseKey='" + licenseKey + "' LIMIT 1";
string query2 = ss.str();
const char* q = query2.c_str();
qstate2 = mysql_query(conn, q);
if (qstate == 0)
{

}
else 
{

}
return true;
}
```

I tried the code above, and it doesn't enter the user's hwid(hardware ID) in that spot. Thats the purpose of these few lines of code.

Comment: Try `mysql_num_rows()`. If it returns 0, the results are empty.

Comment: @Barmar
what would the argument x be?
if(mysql_num_rows(x))
{
//do something
}

Comment: See the example here: https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/mysql_num_rows/cpp-mysql_num_rows-function-examples.html

Comment: It's the result object that was returned by `mysql_store_result()`.